# Intellij IDEA inline documentation doesn't highlight {@code } blocks as monospace

Tags: intellij-idea, codeblocks, javadoc, highlight, monospace

I use IDEA 2016.3 (but the problem existed in previous versions too):

When I call inline documentation (Ctrl+J on Mac, Ctrl+Q on Win) for Java methods it opens *Documentation for* window, and it is pretty good formatted according to JavaDoc guides, except `{@code XXX}` blocks have the same style as normal text. See the attached example for `java.util.HashMap#get` method and compare it with [the reference from Oracle site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)):

[image: missing font style for code blocks]

The root of the problem, probably, that the documentation is already monospaced. So, maybe there is a way to highlight the code blocks with a background? Or to make the default documentation text in non-monospaced font?

UPDATE:
the same issue on Windows with *Segoe UI* default font (non-monospace):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the quick documentation window does not have a monospaced font by default in IntelliJ IDEA. To revert the documentation back to a proportional font:

Invoke *Find Action...* <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and type *Registry* <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Disable the `documentation.component.editor.font` option in the Registry dialog that appears. Be careful with the other configuration options, because it is possible to break your IntelliJ IDEA installation with an incorrect setting.

Comment: on the screenshot i attached the font in the documentation window is obviously monospaced. I've tried `documentation.component.editor.font` change (it is a checkbox, i switched it on now) - the window now has another monospaced font :) (don't know the font name though)

Comment: Have you overridden the default font with a monospaced font in `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance` by any chance?

Comment: i tried to change fort in `Appearance` - same issue. More on that, i've just checked at home on my Win - the same issue! On Win i have default font _Segoe UI_ (non monospaced) and the behavior of _Documentation_ window is the same lame - both text and {@code } have the same font (_Segoe UI_)! See here: https://i.snag.gy/dKblnj.jpg

Comment: Perhaps you should submit [a bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com)

Comment: do you also have the same trouble?

Comment: No, for me documentation is in a proportional font with {@code xxx} sections in a monospaced font.